# How to add PyQt5 layout to parent window and show?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have this code which runs, but the labels do not display. If I do label1.show() then of course it displays, but in its own window. How can I add these labels to a layout, add that to the parent window, and get them to display vertically as QVBoxLayout is supposed to?

```
#Gui
def CreateModule(label_text):
    label = QLabel(label_text)
    label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    label.setStyleSheet("background-color:purple")
    return label

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowTitle("My awesome App")
        self.showMaximized()
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:black")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
label1 = CreateModule('label1')
label2 = CreateModule('label2')
label3 = CreateModule('label3')
layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(label1)
layout.addWidget(label2)
layout.addWidget(label3)
window.setLayout(layout)
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: remove `window.setLayout(layout)`, add `central_widget = QWidget()
window.setCentralWidget(central_widget)` after `label3 = CreateModule('label3')` and change to `layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)`

Comment: If you run your code in a terminal/prompt you'll see the following alert: `QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on MainWindow "", which already has a layout`. You cannot set a layout for a QMainWindow, because it has its own internal layout that cannot be tampered with. You must instead create a QWidget that will be used as *central widget* (with `setCentralWidget()`) and then set the layout for *that* widget.